# Using OGC Filter with GeoNetwork to make CSW request?

Tags: filter, ogc, geonetwork, csw

I have a GeoNetwork catalog with a lot of ISO 19115 metadata. I want to use ogc filters to search into my catalog through CSW services (GetRecords).

So, I use http POST requests. The post data respect GeoNetwork XML schema.

URL :

```
http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw
```

PostData:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csw:GetRecords service="CSW" version="2.0.2" xmlns:csw="http://www/opengis.net/ogc"  
                                              xmlns:ows="http://www/opengis.net/ows" 
                                              xmlns:gml="http://www/opengis.net/gml">
  <csw:Query typeNames="csw:Record>
    <ElementSetName typeNames="csw:Record>full</ElementSetName>
    <csw:Constaint version="1.1.0">
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:Intersects>
          <ogc:PropertyName>ows:BoundingBox</ogc:PropertyName>
          <gml:Envelope>
            <gml:lowerCorner>5 42</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>8 50</gml:upperCorner>
          </gml:Envelope>
        </ogc:Intersects>
      </ogc:Filter>
    </csw:Constaint>
  </csw:Query>
</csw:GetRecords>
```

It works for logical requests (title is ...) but I do not have any result for spatial requests. The response status code is 200 but I have 0 record returned even if I have metadata in the bounding box (Envelope).

Is my post data correct?

Do the lower corner and upper corner correspond to "long lat"?

Do you know good documentation about ogc filter?

I also use ogc filter to update metadata in my GeoNetwork catalog (transaction CSW services) but I can filter only by some tags.

Do you know how to add filters to GeoNetwork? Have I to modify the config-cw.xml GeoNetwork file?

Comment: Why have you tagged this with Java, do you want to make such requests programmatically?

Comment: The csw GetCapabilities response will give you the list of properties you can filter on and the filters

Comment: Yes, I do all my requests programmatically. I have to send a lot of requests and I need to automate the process.

Comment: I found the filters list. Do you know how to add filters? I tried to modify the config-csw.xml geonetwork file but without success for now.

Comment: `Do you know how to add filters?` that's a question for the GeoNetwork developers I think.

Comment: ` I do all my requests programmatically.`  My bad for being too quick on the comment.  Really what I was getting at is that there is no Java code mentioned in the question, and no Java issue, so really the question shouldn't be tagged with Java.